# How to write regexp for getting one specific function parameters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write an python script to collect one specific function's parameters.
Parameters can be in multiple lines like this:

```
str = "getParameters(['ABCD_1','ABCD_2',\
                       'ABCD_3','ABCD_4'])\
```

This works already: (it can catch every words between ' and '):

```
parameters = re.findall(r'\'[\w-]+\'', str)
for parameter in parameters:
   print parameter
```

But I want that only in case of getParameters function the parameters to be collect, and this does not work:

```
getparameters = re.findall(r'getParameters\(\[[\w-]+', str, re.X|re.DOTALL)
for line in getparameters:
    print line
```

Please suggest!

Comment: Just to be completely clear: this is the function parameters of code written in Python using Python?

Comment: To parse python code in python check out the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#module-ast)

Comment: Yes, actually I want to process python code with python regexp.

Comment: What should be your output?

Comment: the parameters of the getParameters function

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using ast, just for fun.

```
import ast

module = ast.parse(
    """getParameters(['ABCD_1','ABCD_2',
                      'ABCD_3','ABCD_4'])""")

for item in module.body:
    if isinstance(item.value, ast.Call) and item.value.func.id == 'getParameters':
        parameters = [each.s for each in item.value.args[0].elts]

print parameters
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I would like to try but: NameError: name 'ast' is not defined

Comment: Hi,Could you please help me in using this AST?

Comment: @Balee13: You forgot the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fixed on using RegEx and if your function occurs exactly once, you can try:

```
re.findall('\'(\w+)\',?', re.search('(getParameters\(.+?\))', x, re.X|re.S).group(1), re.X|re.S)
```

It's not ideal, but it works.  I am sure there is a better way to do this.